# EJB deployment to WildFly results in ClassNotFound

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, wildfly, classnotfoundexception

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_create_application.htm) to learn EJB and remote interfaces. Diverging from the tutorial, I'm using IntelliJ, WildFly and Gradle. I've had some trouble getting my EE project together in IntelliJ, but after reading their docs, skimming tutorials, etc.

Here's the details in aPicturesWorthAThousandWords style:

[Gallery with Project/EJB Window images](http://postimg.org/gallery/370ltonsc/f215967b/)

*(Sorry, I couldn't add images because of low rep!)*

**LibrarySessionRemote:**

```
package com.test.eetestapp;

import javax.ejb.CreateException;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import java.util.List;

@Remote
public interface LibrarySessionRemote {
    void create() throws CreateException;

    void addBook(String bookName);

    List getBooks();
}
```

**LibrarySessionRemoteBean:**

```
package com.test.eetestapp;

import javax.ejb.CreateException;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Stateless(name = "LibrarySessionEJB")
@Remote(LibrarySessionRemote.class)
@TransactionManagement
public class LibrarySessionRemoteBean implements LibrarySessionRemote {
    List<String> bookShelf;

    public LibrarySessionRemoteBean() {
        this.bookShelf = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void create() throws CreateException {

    }

    @Override
    public void addBook(String bookName) {
        bookShelf.add(bookName);
    }

    @Override
    public List getBooks() {
        return bookShelf;
    }
}
```

**ejb-jar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>LibrarySessionEJB</ejb-name>
            <business-remote>com.test.eetestapp.LibrarySessionRemote</business-remote>
            <ejb-class>com.test.eetestapp.LibrarySessionRemoteBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

**Deployment failure/ClassNotFound exception:**

```
/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java -classpath /home/testacc/Apps/idea-IU-162.1447.26/lib/idea_rt.jar:/home/testacc/Apps/idea-IU-162.1447.26/lib/util.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper /tmp/classpath com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 42152 com.intellij.javaee.oss.jboss.agent.JBoss71Agent
[2016-11-18 02:35:45,647] Artifact EjbComponent:ejb: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Connected to server
[2016-11-18 02:35:46,346] Artifact EjbComponent:ejb: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2016-11-18 02:35:47,226] Artifact EjbComponent:ejb: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2016-11-18 02:35:47,227] Artifact EjbComponent:ejb: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYDC0074: Operation failed or was rolled back on all servers. Server failures:" => {"server-group" => {"ha-server-group" => {"host" => {"slave01" => {"ssdp-server01" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"EjbComponent_ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"EjbComponent_ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"EjbComponent_ejb.jar\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.eetestapp.LibrarySessionRemoteBean from [Module \"deployment.EjbComponent_ejb.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.eetestapp.LibrarySessionRemoteBean from [Module \"deployment.EjbComponent_ejb.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"EjbComponent_ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}},"slave02" => {"ssdp-server02" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"EjbComponent_ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"EjbComponent_ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"EjbComponent_ejb.jar\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.eetestapp.LibrarySessionRemoteBean from [Module \"deployment.EjbComponent_ejb.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.eetestapp.LibrarySessionRemoteBean from [Module \"deployment.EjbComponent_ejb.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"EjbComponent_ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}}}}}}}
```

I believe the WildFly setup is correct. I'm using a domain with two host controllers running one server each (within the same server group). I verified this was working by deploying a simple .war to it and seeing results.

Comment: You seem to have a build problem; please show the content of your `build.gradle` file. BTW, I would find a new tutorial because the one that you're using contains a fundamental EJB bug in it - storing state (bookShelf) in a session bean that is supposed to be stateless.

Comment: Your interface is already annotated with `@Remote`. You don't need to add `@Remote(LibrarySessionRemote.class)` annotation on your EJB implementation.

Comment: Also, the `ejb-jar.xml` is unnecessary. Wildfly will automatically pick up your EJB's and register it in your Wildfly EJB container.

Comment: Thanks! I will make the suggested changes. I figured out the problem above as well. It seems my project structure was incorrect. I resolved this by creating a new project with 3 build.gradle files, one for the upper project and one for each module (ejb and client). Now, however, I have an entirely new problem... I'll create a new post as it's unrelated to the details above.